# Ajax request won't display in react render function

Tags: reactjs, axios

I don't know why the result of my axios promise doesn't show up in the render function. I'm using the create-react-app tools by the way.

```
_getPrice() {
const url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot';
axios.get(url)
.then(function (response) {
    //console.log(response.data.data.amount);
    let prices = response.data.data.amount;
    return prices;
}) 
}

render() {
return(<div><h3> {this._getPrice()} </h3></div>);
}
```

Comment: Wel.. you can call `this._getPrice()` on `componentDidMount` and in `_getPrice` function, after getting the data you can store it in state using `setState` and in render you can display data from state and if the data is not present you can show loading message.. , Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

React only re-renders components when either the `state` or `props` of the component change.  If data changes during the render cycle, but doesn't interact with those variables, then the changes will not show up.

You can save the result of your promise to state as follows:

```
getInitialState() {
    return {prices: undefined}
}

componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot';
    axios.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        //console.log(response.data.data.amount);
        let prices = response.data.data.amount;
        this.setState({prices: prices});
    }.bind(this))
}

render() {
    return(<div><h3> {this.state.prices} </h3></div>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you cant call a function in return in render function and if you want update your view you must update state or props...

Answer (score 0):

When requesting data to the server, the request is async, this means it will take time for the server to respond and the browser will continue the execution, than been said, in your current implementation you are returning a promise in your `_getPrice` function and then when the server responds you are not doing anything with the data.

The second problem is that react will only re-render the component when there are changes on the state or on the props, and in your current implementation you are not changing any of that.

Here's a sample of how you need to do it in order to make it work.

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    prices: 0,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot';
    axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        let prices = response.data.data.amount;
        this.setState({ prices });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { prices } = this.state;

    return(
      <div>
        <h3> {prices} </h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Good luck!