# React hooks with AJAX requests

Tags: reactjs, ajax, request, react-hooks, use-effect

### I am using React and I was wondering if I am doing things correctly.

I want to make multiple ajax requests in React for multiple datalists for inputboxes.
I do something like this:

- This is my fetch function

  ```
  function GetData(url, processFunc) {
       ... 
       jquery ajax request using url
       ...
       if (status === 'success') {
           if (processFunc) {
               processFunc(data);
           }
       }
  }
  ```
- A solution which only displays the results that were the fastest.

  ```
   function ComponentA() {
       const [ajaxDataA, setAjaxDataA] = useState(null);
       const [ajaxDataB, setAjaxDataB] = useState(null);
       const [ajaxDataC, setAjaxDataC] = useState(null);
       const [dataA, setDataA] = useState(null);
       ...dataB..
       ...dataC..

       const exampleFunctionA = function(data) {
           ..processes data into result
           setDataA(result);
       }

       const exampleFunctionB = ....
       const exampleFunctionC = ...

       useEffect( () => {
           GetData(url_1, exampleFunctionA);
           GetData(url_2, exampleFunctionB);
           GetData(url_3, exampleFunctionC);       
       }, []);

       return (<>
           ...
           {dataA}
           {dataB}
           ...
       <>);
   }
  ```
- B Solution is why Im asking this question. This works fine but I'm not sure it is correct or this is how hooks were meant to use.

```
function ComponentA() {
    const [ajaxDataA, setAjaxDataA] = useState(null);
    const [ajaxDataB, setAjaxDataB] = useState(null);
    const [ajaxDataC, setAjaxDataC] = useState(null);
    const [dataA, setDataA] = useState(null);
    ...dataB..
    ...dataC..

    useEffect( () => {
        GetData(url_1, setAjaxDataA);
        GetData(url_2, setAjaxDataB);
        GetData(url_3, setAjaxDataC);       
    }, []);
    
    useEffect( () => {
        ..processes data into result
        setDataA(result);
    }, [ajaxDataA]);
    
    ..useEffect ... ,[ajaxDataB] ...
    ... [ajaxDataC] ... 
    
    return (<>
        ...
        {dataA}
        {dataB}
        ...
    <>);
}
```

I have found this solution so I dont repeat the logic. I dont use this solution because I have to process the data so basically instead of

```
 const a = GetData(..., processFunc);
```

I'd use this solution. And so I would still need the useEffects that watch when it refreshes

```
 const a = useFetch(...)
```

[Ajax request won't display in react render function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561489/ajax-request-wont-display-in-react-render-function)

so basically the question is:

### Is solution B a good solution?

Comment: Based  on the instant downvotes I'm doing something wrong. May I ask what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Okay well.. I leave the question up if anyone else had gone on this awful path. So basically **I was waiting for the AJAX requests to finish loading with the useEffect hook**

**At first it looked pretty logical:**

1. I send the request.
2. when it's done it calls the useState hooks' setter function
3. the state variable updates
4. useEffect hook triggers
5. and I do something with the arrived data in the useEffect body

**This was major dumb dumb**
since it refreshed the state like it was forced to, having a gun pointed at its head

It caused inconsistencies:  A child component would want to use the AJAX data before it arrived. It was like a random number generator. Half the time the page loaded and the other half it died running into nullreference exceptions.

### solution: Promise